# Merge data when inserting into another table with the same ID

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table with the following data, the `lab_sample_id` are identical, I’m inserting this data into another table. I would like to merge the data when inserting into another table if the `lab_sample_id` is the same for `leg_id` 1 and 3.

`leg_id` 1 & 3 will always have unique data but the `lab_sample_id` might be identical.

[image]

Here's my current code:

```
INSERT INTO SAMPLE_RESULT   
            (PPK, LAB_SAMPLE_ID, LEG_ID, PT, PT_METHOD, 
             PT_MIN_DETECTION, CU, CU_METHOD, CU_MIN_DETECTION)            
SELECT B.PK, CSR.LAB_SAMPLE_ID, CSR.LEG_ID, CSR.PT, CSR.PT_METHOD, 
       CSR.PT_MIN_DETECTION, CSR.CU, CSR.CU_METHOD, CSR.CU_MIN_DETECTION               
FROM [SOURCE] S
JOIN CLEARING_BATCH CB ON CB.PPK = S.PK
JOIN CLEARING_SAMPLE_RESULT CSR ON CSR.PPK = CB.PK
JOIN SAMPLE_REG SR ON SR.FIELD_SAMP_ID = CSR.LAB_SAMPLE_ID
LEFT JOIN PROSPECTS_AND_MINES PM ON PM.PPK = S.PK
LEFT JOIN LABORATORY L ON L.PPK = PM.PK
LEFT JOIN BATCH B ON L.PK = B.PPK        
WHERE  CB.PK =@Submission_Pk  
       AND  CB.BATCH_ID = B.BATCH_ID    
       AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                      FROM SAMPLE_RESULT SR
                      WHERE SR.PPK = B.PK 
                        AND SR.LAB_SAMPLE_ID = CSR.LAB_SAMPLE_ID 
                        AND SR.LEG_ID = CSR.LEG_ID)
```

Comment: LEG_ID 1 AND 3 will always have unique data but the lab_sample_id might be identical

Comment: if you post your sql as actual text/code (rather than an image) on the question, people can copy it and not have to type everything out.

Comment: are the first 3 fields always populated for `LEG_ID = 1` and the last 3 for `LEG_ID = 3`?

Comment: @Tanner yes that's correct

Comment: @tanner how do i post it, if i paste it here, it says its too long

Comment: @Tanner I have added my SQL code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick, where you can `JOIN` the table to itself:

```
SELECT t1.LAB_SAMPLE_ID, 
       t1.LEG_ID, 
       t1.PT, 
       t1.PT_METHOD, 
       t1.PT_MIN_DETECTION,
       t2.cu, 
       t2.CU_METHOD, 
       t2.CU_MIN_DETECTION
FROM CLEARING_SAMPLE_RESULT t1
INNER JOIN CLEARING_SAMPLE_RESULT t2 
        ON t1.LAB_SAMPLE_ID = t2.LAB_SAMPLE_ID 
WHERE t1.LAB_SAMPLE_ID = 1 AND t2.LAB_SAMPLE_ID = 3
```

Then you can modify your `UPDATE` logic to use this data.